# Dynamic button is not calling the assigned function in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, webforms, controls

I have created an e-comers website but on the view cart page i have dynamicly created delete buttonss
but these buttons do not call the DeleteButton_Click function

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class ViewCart
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim MAXORDER_id As Integer
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
         MAXORDER_id = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("var"))
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            BindCartItems()
            CalculateTotalBill()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub BindCartItems()
        Dim loggedInCustomerId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("LoggedInCustomerID"))
        Dim rowIdCounter As Integer = 0 ' Counter for generating unique IDs


        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim query As String = "SELECT ol.Product_Id, p.Product_Name, p.Product_Price, p.ImageURL, ol.quantity " &
                                  "FROM Order_Line ol INNER JOIN Product p ON ol.Product_Id = p.Product_Id " &
                                  "WHERE ol.order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM orderTable WHERE customer_id = @customerId)"
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", loggedInCustomerId)

            connection.Open()

            cartItems.Controls.Clear() ' Clear previous contents

            Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim productId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(reader("Product_Id"))
                    Dim productName As String = reader("Product_Name").ToString()
                    Dim productPrice As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(reader("Product_Price"))
                    Dim imageURL As String = reader("ImageURL").ToString()
                    Dim quantity As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(reader("quantity"))

                    Dim cartRow As New HtmlGenericControl("div")
                    cartRow.Attributes("class") = "cart-row"

                    cartRow.ID = "cartRow_" & rowIdCounter ' Assign a unique ID to the cart row
                    rowIdCounter += 1

                    Dim productImage As New Image()
                    productImage.Attributes("class") = "product-image"
                    productImage.ImageUrl = imageURL
                    productImage.Width = 50 ' Adjust the image size
                    productImage.Height = 70 ' Adjust the image size


                    Dim productDetails As New HtmlGenericControl("div")
                    productDetails.Attributes("class") = "product-details"
                    productDetails.Style("display") = "flex" ' Use flexbox for horizontal layout
                    productDetails.Style("align-items") = "center" ' Center items vertically
                    productDetails.Style("gap") = "50px" ' Add spacing between items

                    productDetails.InnerHtml = $"<div class='product-name'>{productName}</div>" &
                          $"<div>Price: ${productPrice}</div>" &
                          $"<div>Quantity: {quantity}</div>" &
                          $"<div>Total: ${productPrice * quantity}</div>"

                    Dim deleteButton As New Button()
                    deleteButton.Attributes("class") = "delete-button"
                    deleteButton.Text = "Delete"
                    deleteButton.CommandArgument = productId.ToString() ' Use CommandArgument to store product ID
                    AddHandler deleteButton.Click, AddressOf DeleteButton_Click

                    productDetails.Controls.Add(deleteButton)
                    cartRow.Controls.Add(productImage)
                    cartRow.Controls.Add(productDetails)

                    cartItems.Controls.Add(cartRow)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CalculateTotalBill()
        Dim totalBill As Decimal = 0
        Dim loggedInCustomerId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("LoggedInCustomerID"))

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim query As String = "SELECT SUM(p.Product_Price * ol.quantity) AS TotalBill " &
                              "FROM Order_Line ol " &
                              "INNER JOIN Product p ON ol.Product_Id = p.Product_Id " &
                              "WHERE ol.order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM orderTable WHERE customer_id = @customerId)"
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", loggedInCustomerId)

            connection.Open()

            Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.Read() AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader("TotalBill")) Then
                    totalBill = Convert.ToDecimal(reader("TotalBill"))
                End If
            End Using
        End Using

        totalBillLabel.InnerText = totalBill.ToString("0.00")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DeleteButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim deleteButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Dim productId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(deleteButton.CommandArgument) ' Retrieve the product ID from CommandArgument
        ' Dim loggedInCustomerId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("LoggedInCustomerID"))

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim deleteQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Order_Line WHERE order_id = @MAXORDER_id AND Product_Id = @productId"
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(deleteQuery, connection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAXORDER_id", MAXORDER_id)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productId", productId)

            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        ' Re-bind cart items and recalculate total bill after deleting the item
        BindCartItems()
        CalculateTotalBill()
    End Sub


    Protected Sub btnContinueShopping_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Response.Redirect("shop.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnCheckout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim loggedInCustomerId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("LoggedInCustomerID"))

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim deleteOrderLineQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Order_Line WHERE order_id IN " &
                                                 "(SELECT order_id FROM orderTable WHERE customer_id = @customerId)"
            Dim deleteOrderQuery As String = "DELETE FROM orderTable WHERE customer_id = @customerId"

            Dim deleteOrderLineCommand As New SqlCommand(deleteOrderLineQuery, connection)
            Dim deleteOrderCommand As New SqlCommand(deleteOrderQuery, connection)

            deleteOrderLineCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", loggedInCustomerId)
            deleteOrderCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", loggedInCustomerId)

            connection.Open()

            deleteOrderLineCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            deleteOrderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        ' Re-bind cart items and recalculate total bill after checkout
        BindCartItems()
        CalculateTotalBill()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried to chaged the controls to HTML control but it didn't work either

- THE BindCartItems IS CREATING THE BUTTONS AND OTHER PRODUCT DETAILS
- i WANT TO CALL THE DeleteButton_Click USING THE DELETE BUTTONS

Comment: Are you sure that `DeleteButton_Click` is not being called, or is it that the parameters to the SQL query have gone wrong somehow?

Comment: Keep in mind that for any page post-back, you will have to re-inject those buttons. Any particular reason why they are just dropped into and placed in the markup?

Comment: I'm sure that the delete buttons are not calling the DeleteButton_Click function since i was running the debugger and when the delete button is clicked, it goes to page_load function and after that everything in cartItems div just disappers

Comment: If the cartitems disappears after button click, it means its content is empty at page_load. When you exclude executing BindCartItems() at postback, it causes an empty control because its content is not created yet. If you remove the postback check, page should work.